# The following are equivalent

Tags: general-topology

I have the following proposition which I can't solve. Let $\pi$:$X$ to $Y$ be a surjective continuous map then proof that the following are equivalent:

1. $U \subset Y$ open if and only if $\pi^{−1}(U)$ is open.
2. For all topological spaces, $Z$, $f$ : $Y \to Z$ is continuous if and only if $f \circ \pi$ is continuous.

In particular I am interested on how can we show (2) implies  (1).

It is immediate that   $U \subset Y$ open $\Rightarrow$ $\pi^{−1}$
(U) is open. However I don't see how $\pi^{−1}$
(U) is open $\Rightarrow$ $U\subset Y$ open

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Latex note: \pi for $\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\pi^{-1}[U]$ is open, for $U \subseteq Y$. Define $Z = \{0,1\}$ in the topology $\{\{0\}, Z, \emptyset\}$, and define $f: Y \rightarrow Z$ by $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in U$, $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in Y \setminus U$.

Now, $f \circ \pi$ is continuous, as the only non-trivial open set of $Z$, namely $\{0\}$, has inverse image $\pi^{-1}[U]$.

We conclude from (2) that $f$ is continuous, which means that $U$ is open as the inverse image of $\{0\}$.